# Max Scripting : How can we find number of polygons of an object and save it in a variable?

Tags: max, 3dsmax

Max Scripting : I am creating a script as a beginner, in which I need to calculate number of polygons of any selected object! How can we find it for an object and save it in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `editablemesh` and `editablepoly` objects can be queried for number of faces.
Assuming `obj` is your objects:

```
local numFaces = getNumFaces obj
```

or

```
local numFaces = obj.numFaces
```

If `obj` is a different object which can be evaluated to an `editableMesh` or `editablePoly`, you can use the `.mesh` property of the object:

```
local m = obj.mesh
local numFaces = m.numFaces
free m
```

**edit:**

There is actually:

```
getPolygonCount <obj>
```

which works on all objects regardless of their class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of **triangles**. use this:

```
getPolygonCount <node>
```

If you need the number of polygons in a poly object, you should use the polyop method, but bBeware it counts dead faces as well, so it's a good idea to clean-up the poly before-hand by collapsing the dead stuff:

```
polyop.CollapseDeadStructs <poly>
polyop.getNumFaces <poly>
```